# How to get div whose style is block and values from its hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

E.g., I have 5 divs, each one containing an hidden input field. On startup all divs are hidden by css.

CSS -

```
.divs_nav{
    display:none
}
```

Divs -

```
<div id="1" class="divs_nav"> Div - 1
    <input type="hidden" id="id_qno-1" class="class_qno" value="Question-101" />
</div>
<div id="2" class="divs_nav"> Div - 2
    <input type="hidden" id="id_qno-2" class="class_qno" value="Question-102" />
</div>
<div id="3" class="divs_nav"> Div - 3
    <input type="hidden" id="id_qno-3" class="class_qno" value="Question-103" />
</div>
<div id="4" class="divs_nav"> Div - 4
    <input type="hidden" id="id_qno-4" class="class_qno" value="Question-104" />
</div>
<div id="5" class="divs_nav"> Div - 5
    <input type="hidden" id="id_qno-5" class="class_qno" value="Question-105" />
</div>
```

In the real code, number of these divs may reach upto 500 or more and their appearance is defined by Previous, Next navigation Buttons. But to demonstrate here, I am doing this by 5 buttons and jquery.

Buttons -

```
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="1" class="divButton" />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="2" class="divButton" />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="3" class="divButton" />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="4" class="divButton" />
<input type="button" id="btn-1" value="5" class="divButton"/>
```

Jquery -

```
$('.divButton').click(function() {
    var blockId = this.value;
    document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(2).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(3).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(4).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(5).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "block";
    });
```

Now comes the real **Question** - I have an button outside above mentioned Divs, which is always visible. **What I want is, value of hidden input field from currently visible div** (on this button click).

```
<input type="button" id="activeQno" value="Get Active Q. No." class="activeQno"/>
```

I am completely stuck here. What should be the jquery to get the desired info?

[Link of JsFiddle of this e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/atultiwari/V7CFU/8/)

Thanks. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by assigning a class to it

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/V7CFU/14/

```
$('.divButton').click(function () {
    var blockId = this.value;
    $('.currentQ').removeClass('currentQ');
    document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(2).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(3).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(4).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(5).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "block";
    $('#' + blockId).addClass('currentQ');
});
$('.activeQno').click(function () {
    var value = $('.currentQ').find('input').val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the class suggestion. It's working. but, like i commented to @Nano's reply, in reality I have multiple inputs, sub-divs, tables etc. in above mentioned divs (whose class was `divs_nav`). Then How to get value from hidden input whose class is `class_qno` (and of course, that too of currently visible div). I mean to use something else at `find('input')`, so that it doesnt conflict with other inputs.

Comment: You could use `find('.class_qno')`. It will only look within it's child containers, not siblings.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although all of the 3 answers were correct, but yours one solved all the problems, so i am selecting it as best ans.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all divs which are currently visible with jquery. then select the input in this visible div and then return his value:

```
$('.activeQno').click(function() {
    alert($('.divs_nav:visible > input').val());
});
```

[Here the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7CFU/12/)

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But, I have a doubt, you used `.divs_nav:visible > input` which is Ok for this demo, but in reality I have multiple inputs, sub-divs, tables etc. in above mentioned divs (whose class was `divs_nav`) Then How to get value from hidden input whose class is `class_qno` (and of course, that too of currently visible div). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$('.activeQno').click(function() {
    console.log($(".divs_nav:visible").find("input").val());
});
```

it finds the element that has the class `.divs_nav` that is "visible", uses find() to look inside it and gets the value of the hidden field.

Here is a fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/V7CFU/13/

Comment: Thanks. It's working. but, like i commented to @Nano's reply, in reality I have multiple inputs, sub-divs, tables etc. in above mentioned divs (whose class was `divs_nav`). Then How to get value from hidden input whose class is `class_qno` (and of course, that too of currently visible div). I want to use something specific at `find('input')` so that it only reads input of `class_qno` and doesnt conflict with other inputs.